# I designed my product but when I try to print it there are holes and mistakes in the surface, which I don't see in blender itself. How can I fix it?

Tags: export, 3d-printing

I designed my product but when I try to print it there are holes and mistakes in the surface, which I don't see in blender itself. I have exported it in STL but in the pictures you can see what it looks like before printing.(the last one is how it should look like, and how it looks in Blender)

Do I have to export it in a different format or is it a mistake I've made in my design? What can I do to solve this?

See my design:
[image]

[image: one]
[image: two]
[image: blender]
[image: edit mode]
[image: add on]

Comment: Hello and welcome. Rather than take photos of your monitor post actual screenshots instead, see [How to take a screenshot](https://www.take-a-screenshot.org). Photos are harder to read because we have to look past external interferences (like reflections, smudges or Moiré patterns) and guess if we are looking at hardware issues such as a malfunctioning display or connections, a software level issue like driver malfunction or glitch, or actual artifacts or issues with the model itself.

Comment: I understand your point, however at the moment I only have these photos. I think it should be possible to give some kind of tip or solution for my problem with these. I'd really appreciate it!

Comment: Check if you have flipped normals with _Viewport Overlays > Face Orientation_. Flipped faces are displayed in red. You can also go into edit mode and select _Mesh > Normals > Recalculate Outside_.

Comment: I added another picture, that's how my edit mode looks like. I did the "Recalculate Outside" but it didn't do anything. Where can I find "Viewport Overlays"?

Comment: Your mesh is non-manifold, 3D printers don't like that. Try the addon that's shipped with blender called 3D-print toolbox. It has some features to fix bad geometry

Comment: BTW the question is not about whether we can help you with what you give us, it is whether you respect our work enough to take the time and make the effort to give us something that we don't have to decypher to be able to work with

Comment: I have added another picture where I used the 3D-print toolbox. You can see the results on the last picture but I'm confused on how I can solve these...?

Comment: Try the "Make manifold" button but it's not a magic button, it can't fix everything. unfortunately I think your mesh is pretty much unsalvageable, did you model it using Blender ?

Comment: yess I only used blender. Do you think I won't be able to solve and print it at all?

Answer (score 1):

It is because there are so many errors in the geometry and like someone else mentioned, a lot of it is non-manifold. You need to redo the Boolean operations for the back sides if possible.
[image: one face selected]

In the screen shot above, I have one face selected but you can see it wraps all around the model. The slicer software doesn't know how to interpret this and so you will get lots of problems.

Curious what you are you making by the way?

I would make it like this:

1. Make the whole board as one object.
2. Add in a "cutting" object that encapsulates 1/4 of the board.
3. Duplicate the final board.
4. Use the cutting object to boolean both the board models. One would use the difference operation and one would use the intersect operation.
5. Repeat this for the other section you want to split up

Something like this:
[image: First boolean]

I have the "cutting" object selected and displayed as wireframe in the screenshot above.

You would then get nice clean geometry
[image: Happy!]

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! How do I go about that?

I'm currently working on my final assignment from the school before I go to university. Witt my friend we have created a new board-game and this is supposed to be the board in the shape of a vulcano. What you can see on the pictures is a quarter of it:)

Comment: I edited my post above to show how I might tackle a project like this! Hope it helps :)

Comment: Thank you!!! I'll try it out and report back to you:)

Comment: It worked, thank you Quentin for helping me solve my problem! I was able to print it  and can now finish my project :)

Comment: Awesome! I’m glad it helped. I hope everything works out well :)